# Javascript slideshow array issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am currently new to Javascript and I am stuck on this problem. The goal of this code is to cycle through 3 different combinations of separate text(slide) and images(slideimg) upon pressing the previous and next buttons. Currently my code works perfectly when going from element 0 to 2 in the array, both up and down, but I need the array to reset back to [0] while the [2] element is active and the next button is pressed, while also giving the active class to [0] and removing the active class from [2]. I also need the array to do the opposite when the previous button is pressed while [0] is active. I have tried a few variations of solutions, but no luck with displaying the content properly so far.

```
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".slideimg");
const prevButton = document.getElementById("larrow");
const nextButton = document.getElementById("rarrow");

var currentSlide = 0;
slides[currentSlide].classList.add("active");
imgs[currentSlide].classList.add("active");

var nextSlide = function(){


    if(currentSlide < 2) {
        currentSlide+=1;
    }

    slides[currentSlide - 1].classList.remove("active");
    slides[currentSlide].classList.add("active");
    imgs[currentSlide - 1].classList.remove("active");
    imgs[currentSlide].classList.add("active");
};

var prevSlide = function(){
    if(currentSlide > 0){
        currentSlide--;
    }

    slides[currentSlide].classList.add("active");
    slides[currentSlide + 1].classList.remove("active");
    imgs[currentSlide].classList.add("active");
    imgs[currentSlide + 1].classList.remove("active");
};

nextButton.addEventListener("click", nextSlide);
prevButton.addEventListener("click", prevSlide);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `active` from the current slide initially. Then change `currentSlide` by adding 1 and using modulo:

```
const nextSlide = function () {
    slides[currentSlide].classList.remove('active');
    imgs[currentSlide].classList.remove('active');

    currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % 3;

    slides[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
    imgs[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
};
```

Do the same for `prevSlide`, except change the `currentSlide` assignment to:

```
currentSlide = (currentSlide + 2) % 3;
```

(The `+ 2` carries out the same sort of logic as `- 1`, except that it will land on the correct number when the slide starts at 0. Modulo won't work as desired on a negative number; `-1 % 2` gives you `-1`, not `2`)